# Read page source after page fully loaded (JavaScript executed)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code that waits for javascript rendering to complete.

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(url);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3000);
wait.until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
    public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
          }
        );
```

The question is, how do I read the page source after it's done? The method below doesn't guarantee that it will return the source of the modified page according to its documentation.

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps, this is not really an answer, but it's text is too long for a comment

first at all, what do you want to achieve?

as far as i tried and found out, `ChromeDriver`s `getPageSource()` returns the "current" source-code. not the source-code initially sent from the server.

the problem with javascript-loaded pages seems to be, that the browser receives a pages content and after interpreting and rendering it initially, for the browser the document is ready

requests via javascript do not change (can not change?) `document.readyState`

so, after  a page is loaded and rendered initially, everthing else is "just" dom-manipulation

some suggest to scroll down as long as end of page is reached and/or a certain element is found at the page

**but**

lets say you have to scroll 50,000 pixels down to end of page, if previous elements are removed by javascript, you will never ever get the "whole" source-code at once

in my mind you have to ask yourself the question what you want to achieve

for me something like the following code works:

```
private void performScrollToEndOfPage(final WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
    final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Long prev = null;
    while (true) {
        this.checkItems(driver);
        long val = 2000;
        if (prev != null) {
            val += prev.longValue();
        }
        final Object current = js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, " + Long.toString(val) + ");return window.pageYOffset;");
        if (!(current instanceof Long)) {
            break;
        }
        // 1000 milliseconds by try and error, if this value is too low, increase it
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if (current.equals(prev)) {
            break;
        }
        prev = (Long) current;
    }
}

private void checkItems(final WebDriver driver) {
    final List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for (final WebElement anchor : elements) {
        final String href = anchor.getAttribute("href");
        if ((href == null) || href.isBlank() || href.isEmpty()) {
            // TODO: throw Exception or whatever
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit - in reply to your comment**

as far as i gathered from your comment, your intention seems to be something like a reverse engineering.

and i think, it's almost impossible to create a "generic" link-crawler.

therefore you might know the pages source-code and about all its dependencies very very well.

you could trace/capture network-traffic while clicking "all available elements" on a page

a (probably weird) example i can give to you is for instagram:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Analyzer {
    private final String baseUrl = "https://www.instagram.com";
    private final WebDriver driver;
    private final Set<String> hrefs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private final String profileName;

    private Analyzer(final String profileName) {
        super();
        this.profileName = profileName;
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public String getBaseUrl() {
        return this.baseUrl;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }

    public String getProfileName() {
        return this.profileName;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.getDriver().get(this.getUrl());
        this.performScrollToEndOfPage();
        this.getDriver().quit();
        final Iterator<String> iterator = this.hrefs.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final String href = iterator.next();
            final boolean linkBroken = this.isLinkBroken(href);
            // remove unbroken links
            if (!linkBroken) {
                // remove unbroken URLs/hrefs
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        // TODO: handle broken links
        System.out.println(this.hrefs);
    }

    private void collectOperation() {
        // collect whatever you want
        // items with src-attribute (for example image-tags),
        // action-attribute (for example form-tags) or
        // href-attribute (for example anchor-tags)
        // and evaluate the attributes value(s)
        final List<WebElement> elements = this.getDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for (final WebElement anchor : elements) {
            final String href = anchor.getAttribute("href");
            final List<WebElement> images = anchor.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
            if ((href == null) || href.isBlank() || href.isEmpty() || (images == null) || images.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            this.hrefs.add(href);
        }
    }

    private String getUrl() {
        return this.getBaseUrl() + "/" + this.getProfileName();
    }

    private boolean isLinkBroken(final String href) {
        try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();) {
            final HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(href);
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            // TODO: logging or something else
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void performScrollToEndOfPage() {
        final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
        // This will scroll the web page till end.
        Long prev = null;
        while (true) {
            this.collectOperation();
            // scroll by 2000px
            long val = 2000;
            if (prev != null) {
                val += prev.longValue();
            }
            final Object current = js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, " + Long.toString(val) + ");return window.pageYOffset;");
            try {
                // try and error, if this value is too low, increase it
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                // TODO: logging or something else
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!(current instanceof Long)) {
                break;
            }
            if (current.equals(prev)) {
                break;
            }
            prev = (Long) current;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // i hope Microsoft will be lenient with me
        final String profileName = "microsoft";
        final Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(profileName);
        analyzer.run();
    }
}
```

instagram works quite the same as "our" page. you can scroll down to the very end of someones "page", and you will only get approximately 35 posts.

regardless of using the drivers `findElements` or `getPageSource`-Method and parsing `getPageSource`s `return`-value with (for example) `Jsoup`

Comment: For this specific case, I am trying to find all broken links, including the ones generated by JS. And the assumption is that I don't know the page contents, so I cannot wait for any specific page element. It would be a generic broken link crawler.